# Exercise 24.13 of T. Jech's *Set Theory*

Tags: set-theory

Having struggled my way through most of chapter 24 of Jech's *Set Theory*, I'm stuck on the very last part of the very last question, 24.13:

> Let $I=I_{NS}$ be the nonstationary ideal on $\omega_1$, let $c_{\gamma}$, $\gamma<\omega_1$, be the constant functions (with value $\gamma$) on $\omega_1$, and let $d(\alpha)=\alpha$ be the diagonal function. The function $d$ is a least upper bound, but not an exact upper bound of the set $\{c_{\gamma}:\ \gamma<\omega_1\}$, in $<_I$.

I have shown that $d$ is a least upper bound, but I am unable to find an $f\in\omega_1^{\omega_1}$ with $f<_Id$ such that $c_{\gamma}<_If$ for all $\gamma<\omega_1$, to show that $d$ is not an exact upper bound. Hints are very welcome.

Comment: For those (like me) who hadn’t seen *exact upper bound* before, $d$ is an exact upper bound of $C=\{c_\gamma:\gamma<\omega_1\}$ in $\left\langle{}^{\omega_1}\omega_1,<_I\right\rangle$ iff $C$ is cofinal in $\left\{f\in{}^{\omega_1}\omega_1:f<_I d\right\}$.

Comment: @Brian: That surprises me a little bit. You haven't seen what is perhaps the most basic definition of PCF? And I know that PCF is quite useful in set theoretical topology...

Comment: @Asaf: PCF theory was just starting to enter set-theoretic topology in a big way about the time that I stopped doing research.

Comment: @Brian: Ah. That makes sense. BGU had a postdoc for two years that did that sort of stuff (mostly with Kojman). I think he's in Ohio now.

Comment: @Asaf: His home page seems to put him at BGU. Is he or Shelah responsible for the lovely title *Fallen Cardinals*?

Comment: @Brian: Oh, that's a tough cookie. Both have a fitting sense of humor for this sort of title.

Answer (score 3):

In order to show that $f$ is not an exact upper bound you need to find a $g \lt_I d$ that is not bounded by any $c_\gamma$.

Using Solovay's theorem let $\{S_\alpha:\alpha \lt \omega_1\}$ be a partition of $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$ disjoint stationary sets. Then define $g(\alpha) = min \{i \le \alpha : \alpha \in S_i \}$ if it exists, 0 otherwise.

Comment: That's what happens when you stay up for 24 hours after sleeping only two the morning before... :-)

Comment: (For $\omega_1$ or any successor, this is not Solovay's theorem but Ulam's.)

Comment: To make things clearer, we should let $T_\alpha := S_\alpha \setminus (\alpha + 1)$, and define $g(\alpha) = i$ if $\alpha \in T_i$, and $0$ if no such $0$ exists. $T_i$ are of course still stationary, and one can check by definition that:
$$
\{\alpha < \omega_1 : g(\alpha) \geq d(\alpha)\} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} (\alpha + 1) \cap T_\alpha = \emptyset
$$